# 'SyntaxError' while unpacking dict in Python

Tags: python

When I am trying to run an example of [pychromecast](https://github.com/ur1katz/pychromecast/blob/master/pychromecast) library, I get the following failure:

```
~/pychromecast $ python example.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "example.py", line 11, in <module>
import pychromecast.controllers.youtube as youtube
File "/home/pi/pychromecast/pychromecast/controllers/youtube.py", line 27
REQUEST_PARAMS_SET_PLAYLIST = {**BASE_REQUEST_PARAMS, **SET_PLAYLIST_METHOD}
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've tried running this in both Python2 and Python3. What is wrong here?

Comment: Link to offending line: https://github.com/ur1katz/pychromecast/blob/master/pychromecast/controllers/youtube.py#L27

Comment: This means that the library only supports modern Python. `{**BASE_REQUEST_PARAMS, **SET_PLAYLIST_METHOD}` works in Python 3.5 and above.

Comment: Thanks! That explains it, I've got Python 3.4.5

Answer (score 3):

This syntax was released with Python 3.5 as the part of [PEP 448 - Additional Unpacking Generalizations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/).

As per the [document](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-448): since Python 3.5, tuple, list, set, and dictionary displays allow multiple unpackings like:

```
>>> *range(4), 4
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)

>>> [*range(4), 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

>>> {*range(4), 4, *(5, 6, 7)}
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}

>>> {'x': 1, **{'y': 2}}
{'x': 1, 'y': 2}
```

Comment: `{*..., *...}` would create a set, but `{**..., **...}` creates a dictionary.